# Update UIImageView while cycle running

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
 CGFloat coef = tempCount / 20;
 while(tempCount >= 0)
 {
  [imgView setTransform: CGAffineTransformRotate([imgView transform], -1*coef)];
  tempCount -=coef;
  [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval: 0.09];
 }
}
```

And the problem is in than, that my image on the image view updates only after cycle. I want it to update every 0.09 seconds. What can you propose? Thanx!

Comment: What are you trying to do? just gradually rotate imageview?

Comment: yes, exactly! I want to show on the screen slow animation with rotation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rotate a view with animation use animation facilities SDK provides for you. To rotate your view on full 360 degrees you will need to use core animation.

The following code will rotate your view during 3 sec:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
...
CABasicAnimation* animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 2*M_PI];
animation.duration = 3.0f;
animation.repeatCount = 1.0f;
[imgView.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"MyAnimation"];
```

Or try the following - I have not tested the code, but it should reset view's transform to identity with animation:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"Reset dial" context: nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration: 1.0f];
[UIView setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

[imgView setTransform:CGAffineTransformIdentity];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: No. I am trying to do phone with a dial up. In function touchMoved I'm rotating my phone circle to the right and when I'm touchEnd I need to restore my image to the previous angle but with some animation delay.